# Rename column in mysql without data population

Tags: mysql, alter, table-rename

In mysql
When we use `alter table` syntax for rename a column, a data population will be happening for that column.
 For example think this case,

```
create table table1(i int(10) primary key,k varchar(10));

alter table table1 change k j varchar(10);
```

here we want only rename a column, not data-type. Anyway we have to declare a data-type in above case. So, a iteration will be happening to change data even data-types are same. We do not want this iteration.

My question,

Is there any option to reduce this iteration?  or  Is there any option to rename a column without this iteraion?

Comment: The docs tell you you have to include the data type. Is there a reason why you don't want that "iteration" you talk about?

Comment: There are ways that involve juggling around `.frm` files: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html check the remark by  Mark Mackay on July 9 2004 6:11am

Comment: are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?